# admin-ajax.php returning 0

Tags: plugins, ajax, email

I'm currently working on a WordPress contact form, which is created as a plugin. I need the form after submit to send an email without reloading the page. When it reloads everything is ok. The problem is when submit button is pressed and e.preventDefault() is active the browser shows me 500 (Internal Server Error) with admin-ajax.php = 0

P.S The post is edited

```
<?php
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'html_form_code' ); // Write our JS below here
    //
    function html_form_code() {
    ?>
    <form action="<?php esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )?>" method="post" class="contact-form" id="contact-form" >
        <div class=header-contact>
            <p><h2>Contact Form</h2></p>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class=input-containers>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="" size="40" placeholder="Име и фамилия"/>
        </div>
        <div class=input-containers>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="cf-email" value="" size="40" placeholder="Поща"/>
        </div>
        <div class=input-containers>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="" size="40" placeholder="Относно"/>
        </div>
        <div class=input-containers>
            <textarea rows="10" id="message" cols="35" name="cf-message" placeholder="Текст"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class=input-containers>
            <input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send" id="submitForm">
        </div>
        <p id="verify" style="display:none;">Your message has been sent.<br /><br /></p> 
    </form>
    <script>
jQuery('#contact-form').submit(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();
     var name =  jQuery('#name').val();
     var email =  jQuery('#email').val();
     var subject =  jQuery('#subject').val();
     var message =  jQuery('#message').val();
              jQuery.ajax({
               url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
               type: "POST",
               data:{ 
                  action: 'send_email', 
                  name: name,
                  email: email,
                  subject: subject,
                  message: message,
                    },
               success:function(res){
        alert("Email Sent.");
        }
     }); 
    });
</script>
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_email', 'deliver_mail' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'deliver_mail' );

    function deliver_mail() {
        require_once "wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php";
        if (isset($_POST["cf-submitted"])) {

            // sanitize form values
            $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
            $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
            $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
            $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

            // get the blog administrator's email address

            //$to = "email@gmx.com";
            $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

            // Localhost
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
            $mail->Host = "mail.gmx.com";      // sets GMX as the SMTP server for example: mail.gmx.com
            $mail->Port = 465;                 // set the SMTP port for the GMX server


            $mail->Username = $email;
            $mail->Password = 'pass';

            $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
            $mail->AddAddress($email);

            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->MsgHTML($message);

            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";

            try {
                $mail->send();
                $msg = "An email has been sent for verfication.";
                $msgType = "success";

                wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 302 );
                exit();

            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                $msg = $ex->getMessage();
                $msgType = "warning"; 

                wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 302 );
                exit();
            }  

    add_action( 'init', function() {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['form_submitted'] ) ) {
            deliver_mail();        
        }
    });

    function cf_shortcode() {
        ob_start();
        //deliver_mail();
        html_form_code();

        //ob_end_flush(); 
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    add_shortcode( 'contact_form_second', 'cf_shortcode' );
```

Comment: First you forgot the action parameter in your ajax call. Second the url in ajax call is not correct. Why do you call "deliver_mail()" in the init hook? [WP Codex: AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: I downvoted because there was no effort to debug the code http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/. edit your question to add more informations.

Comment: I copied the full plugin code, this is all the information which is possible...

Comment: It is in the init hook because it prevents from "Cannot modify header information"...

Comment: Okay....but if you send your form via ajax you do not need that.

Comment: With or without it "e.preventDefault()" stops the form to send an email

Comment: Have you looked at my first comment? You forget the action and the URL is wrong. Your ajax hooks (  wp_ajax_my_action and wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action) are never called.

Comment: As user141080 mentioned, the url should point admin-ajax.php

Comment: I edited the code, look at it.